# Dynamic buttons with images with Kivy

Tags: python, image, button, kivy

## Problem

I have a button with a circular image with the ratio 1:1, and when I run the code (at the bottom), the program creates a screen with the same ratio, but I can resize it, and change the ratio and size, but the image does not grow as the screen, so it uses less space as the screen grows. I tried to set values for the `size_hint:`, but it distorts the image, minus in a single proportion. How can I make this button adaptable to any proportion and size, without distortion and with the space proportional to the size of the screen?

#### Generated Screen (1:1)

[image: Generated Screen]

#### Resized Screen (16:9)

[image: Resized Screen]

### Code

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class FloatingApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

flApp = FloatingApp()

flApp.run()
```

### .kv File

```
<Botao@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size: 138, 138
    background_normal: 'bd.png'
    background_down: 'bd1.png'
    background_color: 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 1  
    size_hint: None, None

<FloatLayout>:
    Botao:

        text:"Botao"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the size of your `Botao` in your `kv` file as a function of the `root.size`. By using `min(root.size)`. You must also remove the `size: 138, 138` line.

```
<Botao@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    #size: 138, 138
    background_normal: 'bd.png'
    background_down: 'bd1.png'
    background_color: 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 1  
    size_hint: None, None

<FloatLayout>:
    Botao:
        size: (min(root.size)*0.5, min(root.size)*0.5)
        text:"Botao"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```